# Get and set enviroment variables on mono and possible alternative

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I got a little c# dll that implements a message queue service and on windows it runs perfectly.
To locate all the queues i use an enviroment variable stored in Machine during the installation.

System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PHMQ", install_dir , EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);

Now i just tryed to run it on Mono, and when the programs run it throw an exception.
The PHMQ service is not installed.

After 2 hours of search, i discovered that Mono doesn't really store this kind of variables it just send them to null.
(a simple text file was too simple ?)

So, the question is: How can i solve this problem ?
The first idea was : if is running on linux put it in a specific folder like /opt, but it's a dll, if do it in this way any program that want to use it must be executed like root

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have your program append a line to /etc/environment to set the env var for the machine. Obviously to modify that file you'll need root, so it should be done during the installation process.

However, a known location would be better IMO. I can't see why you wouldn't be able to execute from /opt.

Comment: Infact i solved it in this way, during the installation it trequire your root pass and set chmod 777 over a new folder under /var/.
I fixed it last week but i forgot to vcse the question :)